# What is the purpose of this.$nextTick?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I'm new to Vue js and I'm trying to understand the logic of the usage of nextTick in a method. So I have two components like this:

IsTuruIslem.vue

```
<template>
...
  <t-row>
      <is-turu-islem-goruntule ref="isTuruIslemGoruntule" 
                              @kaydet="kaydet" 
                              @guncelle="guncelle">
      </is-turu-islem-goruntule>
    </t-row>
...
</template>
<script>
...
    isTuruIslemPopupAc(detay) {
      if (!detay) this.$refs.isTuruIslemGoruntule.open();
      else {
        let guncellenecekDetay = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(detay));
        console.log("Popup:", guncellenecekDetay);
        this.$refs.isTuruIslemGoruntule.open({
          isUpdate: true,
          detay: guncellenecekDetay
        });
      }
    }
...
</script>
```

IsTuruIslemGoruntule.vue

```
<template>
...
<t-row>
      <t-col :span="20">
        <t-select
          id="sirket"
          ref="sirket"
          label="Şirket *"
          v-model="detay.sirket"
          item-value="id"
          item-text="aciklama"
        />
      </t-col>
    </t-row>
    <t-row>
      <t-col :span="20">
        <t-select
          id="cmb_durum"
          ref="durum"
          label="Durum"
          itemText="text"
          itemValue="id"
          v-model="detay.durumBaseDTO"
          :readonly="false"
          :clearable="true"
          :disabled="false"
        />
      </t-col>
....
</template>
<script>
...
methods: {
    open: function(options) {
      this.isOpen = true;
      if (options) {
        this.isUpdate = true;
        this.detay = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(options.detay));
      } else {
        this.detay = {};
      }
      //this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs.durum
        .get("/ytts/api/common/durumlar/aktifPasif", null)
        .then(data => {})
        .catch(err => null);

      this.$refs.islem
        .get("/ytts/api/tanimYonetimi/isTuruIslem/sorgula/islemListesi")
        .then(data => {})
        .catch(err => null);

      this.$refs.sirket
        .get("/ytts/api/tanimYonetimi/isTuruIslem/sorgula/sirketListesi")
        .then(data => {})
        .catch(err => null);
      //});
      //console.log("DETAY:", this.detay);
    },
...
</script>
```

My question is code as in this example doesn't work properly and I get "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" at the line where this.$refs.durum exists. But when I uncomment the nextTick method which resides at the top of this.$refs.durum, it magically works. I really don't get the idea of this usage. Can someone clearly explain it to me? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2019/01/22/vue-what-is-next-tick/

Comment: Dude I read that document but still there are questions in my head :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `<t-select ref="durum">` component is not created (by using `v-if`, for example) then `this.$refs.durum` won't exist.

Let's say you use something like `v-if="show"` with `show` set to false to control the creation of that component. If, in your method, you set `show` to true, then the component won't be created as soon as you do so, you have to wait until Vue has updated the DOM (this is a performance thing). For this, you need to use `$nextTick` to wait until that time, only then will the component be created and `this.$refs.durum` will exist.

You haven't provided all of your code, so I can't say for sure, but it looks like maybe `isOpen` is controlling the visibility of that component.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :) By the way, yes I set the visibilty of the dialog component, now that's all clear :)